# what do these equivalence sets look like? $x$~$y$ if $x-y$ rational,

Tags: real-analysis

For this equivalence relation, for $x,y \in R [0,1], x$~$y$ whenever $x-y$ is rational

What do these classes look like? Is there one class that is all of the rational numbers, and then every irrational number is in its own class?

Because $1-q \in Q $ whenever $q$ is rational, so does that mean every rational number is in the equivalence class $[1]$, therefore there is only one equivalence class that holds rational numbers because equivalence classes partition a set?

Comment: Yes the rationals form one single class.  No the irrationals aren't all in their own classes, $\sqrt 2 \sim 1+\sqrt 2$, for example.

Comment: @lulu The group of all classes under this relation and addition appears in one construction of Vitali sets.

Comment: The equivalence classes are *translates* of $\Bbb Q$ (with $\Bbb Q$ itself being one of them)

Comment: If the rationals are all in one single class, then why is this class considered a translate of $Q$?

I see how $\sqrt{2}$~$q + \sqrt{2}$ is an equivalence class. It's more of a replacement of $\sqrt{2}$ with every rational number, instead of a "translation" though, right?

What is the story behind calling them translates?

Comment: @Frank they're "translates" in the sense of the number line. If you think of the rationals as a subset of the number line, then your set $\{q+\sqrt{2}|q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ consists of the rationals "translated" $\sqrt{2}$ to the right on the number line.

Answer (score 1):

These properties might help you visualise these sets better:

each equivalence class is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. This follows from the density of rational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. To be precise, let $q_n$ be a sequence of rational numbers converging to $r-x$, where $r$ is real. Then $\{x+q_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequene in the equivalence class of $x$ that converges to $r$.

Also, as with any equivalence relation, the equivalence classes split $\mathbb{R}$  into a disjoint subsets, which do not intersect, and their union is the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

As you pointed out, $\mathbb{Q}$ is an equivalence class, say $[0]$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let $\sqrt 3 = \sqrt 2 + x$ for some number $x$. Then $3 = 2 + 2x\sqrt 2 + x^2$ and so $$\sqrt 2 = \frac{3-x^2}{2x}.$$
If $x$ were rational, the right-hand side would be rational, but the left-hand side is not.
So $x$ cannot be rational, i.e., $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ are not in the same equivalence class.